# Are there any Good Compilations of Socrates?

Tags: socrates, ancient-philosophy, greeks

Fellow Thinkers, does anyone know of a book that has compiled all the main sources that we know Socrates from (Plato, Xenophon, Aristophanes, ...)?

Thank you for your time. - SDH

Comment: See SEP's entry on [Socrates](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/socrates/) as well as Taylor, [Socrates](https://books.google.it/books?id=RgulDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) and Reeve, [The Trials of Socrates : Six Classic Texts of Plato Xenophon Aristophanes (2002)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ha1i_HeBi8QC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mauro](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/4752/mauro-allegranza) has pointed out in the comment above, see [Six Classic Texts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0872205894).

Best of Fortune.